# wordpress Rest api Image link in Post properties

Tags: wordpress, rest, properties

As it is known, wordpress rest api works in a way that the Get request of any post gives us a post including a featured_media property, for Imaging purposes.
I have a situation where I need to get 100 Posts and I do that quite easy with 'wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100' and it works well, but the problem is that I need to get images for each post too. To do so I have to make each additional request for each post to get its Image.... so to get 100 posts, I have to send 101 requests and it is horrible waste of resources and time. 
What should I do to include image link in the Post properties to save my 100 requests and do everything with just a single request.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the REST API response content - **it can contain the information you want**.

This was one of my examples, where I wanted to include a custom field value:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'slug_register_embed_youtube' );
// "venue" is a custom post type I created using the WP Types plugin
function slug_register_embed_youtube() {
    // first register the field with WP REST API
    register_rest_field( 'venue',
        'meta_data',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'venue_get_meta',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}

function venue_get_meta($post, $field_name, $request) {
    // I wanted the value to appear in the response as "youtube_embed", 
    // and I wanted the "wpcf-youtube-embed" custom field's value there
    $meta_data = array(
        'youtube_embed' => get_post_meta($post[ "id" ], 'wpcf-youtube-embed')[ 0 ],
    );
    return $meta_data;
}
```

The code above modified the response:

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "date": "2016-06-08T16:37:23",
    "date_gmt": "2016-06-08T16:37:23",
    "guid": {
      "rendered": "http://www.example.com/wp/?post_type=venue&#038;p=20"
    },
    "modified": "2016-06-20T11:45:22",
    "modified_gmt": "2016-06-20T11:45:22",
    "slug": "aquarium-club",
    "type": "venue",
    "link": "http://www.example.com/wp/venue/aquarium-club/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Aquarium Club"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<p>Aquarium Club. That&#8217;s OK. 7765e546uzfkjglh</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<style>\n.gmap-iframe-container {\nmax-width: 100%;\n}\n.gmap-iframe {\nwidth: 100%;\nheight: 200px;\nmin-width:100%;\n}\n</style>\n<div class=\"gmap-iframe-container\">\n<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2695.565888030695!2d19.052103115616678!3d47.49836967917771!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4741dc402a04eee3%3A0x6869564cd433693c!2sAkv%C3%A1rium+Klub!5e0!3m2!1shu!2shu!4v1466147278469\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen class=\"gmap-iframe\"></iframe></p>\n"
    },
    "excerpt": {
      "rendered": "<p>Aquarium Club. That&#8217;s OK. 7765e546uzfkjglh &nbsp;</p>\n"
    },
    "featured_media": 0,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "format": "standard",
    "tags": [],
    "meta_data": {
      "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xBW7DglTDGs"
    },
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue/20"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/venue"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/types/venue"
        }
      ],
      "wp:attachment": [
        {
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=20"
        }
      ],
      "wp:term": [
        {
          "taxonomy": "post_tag",
          "embeddable": true,
          "href": "http://www.example.com/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=20"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Notice, that I have this

```
"meta_data": {
    "youtube_embed": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/xBW7DglTDGs"
},
```

after the "tags" array.

You can find all the information for modifying response in WP REST API v2 here: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/

Comment: Thats exactly what I want but where should I write that code?

Comment: I put it in the functions.php. Actually with the add_action() you place it not really / only in a "location" but in the "order of functions" that WP executes when the file is called. As the theme's function.php is called every time the page is refreshed, your code will be there with every page refresh (and of course, every REST API query).